# SQL 2008 OraOLEDB.Oracle Provider returning "exceeded simultaneous SESSIONS_PER_USER limit"

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, openrowset

We have an SQL job that when run as standard user (with appropriate access) returns the error seen in the title.  However when we change the job to run as 'sa', it works flawlessly.  The same parameters are being passed to the OPENROWSET function to connect to the OraOLEDB.Oracle provider (it's using the same Oracle ID/PW to login).  It is NOT a linked Oracle server; it's ad-hoc.

Has anyone ever seen anything like this before?

Running Oracle 11g, SQL 2008 R1

Answer (score 3):

The error indicates that more database sessions are being created than are allowed according to the `SESSIONS_PER_USER` limit on the Oracle database user that the application is connecting as.  This is designed to limit the number of sessions a particular Oracle database user can have open at any one time.  I'm hard-pressed to envision why the SQL Server user that a job is run as would influence the number of Oracle database sessions that are created.

What is the `SESSIONS_PER_USER` limit for the Oracle user in question

```
SELECT limit
  FROM dba_profiles p
       JOIN dba_users u ON (p.profile = u.profile)
 WHERE u.username = <<oracle database user name>>
   AND p.resource_name = 'SESSIONS_PER_USER'
```

Can you monitor the `GV$SESSION` table in Oracle to see how many sessions actually exist for the user in question throughout the process to make sure that there isn't a stray session or two that are really creating the problem rather than the SQL Server user name change causing and resolving the issue?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM gv$session
 WHERE username = <<oracle database user name>>
```

Comment: Justin, I find it hard to believe as well, but that's precisely what's happening.  I don't have admin/control over the Oracle server so I can't run any of those queries you provided.

Comment: @Brad - Can you ask the DBA of the Oracle database to run them?  It's obviously hard to debug if we can't exclude the possibility that there are some Oracle database sessions that you're not aware of that potentially aren't related to your application that are causing or at least contributing to the problem.

Comment: I'm going to see if I can get in touch with an administrator to monitor gv$session when the job is run as SA vs the normal SQL user.